# Warhammer 40,000: Mechanicus - What does initiative do?

Tags: warhammer-40k-mechanicus

During missions, some of your decisions can result in (for example):

[image: INIT--]

Which in this case results in:

[image]

And it appears to be a good thing.

But what does it exactly do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah just discovered it means your units start first prior to the enemy:

[image: Initiative advantage to Tech Priests]